# SwiftUI: @StateObject deinit NOT called?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext

    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.timestamp, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(items) { item in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)")
                    } label: {
//                        Text(item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
                        ItemCellView(model: ItemCellViewModel(item: item))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(context: viewContext)
            newItem.timestamp = Date()

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}

private let itemFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .medium
    return formatter
}()

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, PersistenceController.preview.container.viewContext)
    }
}


struct ItemCellView: View {
    
    @StateObject var model:ItemCellViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Text(model.item.timestamp!, formatter: itemFormatter)
            .foregroundColor(.blue)
    }
    
}

class ItemCellViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var item:Item
    
    init(item:Item) {
        self.item = item
    }
    
    deinit {
        print("ItemCellViewModel EDINIT \(self)")
    }
    
}
```

It draws this:

[image]

PROBLEM:

`ItemCellViewModel` deinit is NOT called after I swipe to delete the item.
Can someone tell me why the `ItemCellViewModel` sticks around even after the `ItemCellView` is gone?

This is a simplified version of a codebase I am working in. I need that model to go away when the view is "deleted" by the user. Why is SwiftUI keeping `ItemCellViewModel` around??

Comment: View is not deleted in a fact (just removed from visible area) because List caches some number of views (visible area + ~2) and StateObject is persistent storage of view which keeps its state. So observed behavior is by-design.

Comment: I see. This makes sense. This is a problem because when I switch tabs (in another app with same pattern) another view allows for the "Item" entity deletion and then when I come back to this view the app crashes since the `ItemCellViewModel` still holds on to `Item`. Will post another question about it. Your comment seems to be the actual answer to this question.

Comment: @Asperi if you post your comment as an answer we can mark it as such. I have tested the caching behavior you outlined. Your comment is the correct answer.

Comment: `@StateObject` is probably not what you want here.  Just pass the `item` directly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View is not deleted in a fact (just removed from visible area) because List caches some number of views (visible area + ~2) and StateObject is persistent storage of view which keeps its state. So observed behavior is by-design.

Answer (score -1):

for me, using `ObservedObject` instead `StateObject` in that case fixed the issue, and the deinit function was called.

Answer (score -6):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct is a view model already there is no need for view model objects. If you try to use objects for view data instead of the struct you'll run into the kind of consistency bugs that SwiftUI's use of value types was designed to eliminate. SwiftUI diffs these structs to create/update/remove UIView objects automatically.

`@StateObject` is for when you want to use a reference type in `@State`, e.g. you want to do something asynchronous with a lifetime tied to something on screen, like a Combine pipeline.

This is all covered in [SwiftUI Essentials WWDC 2019](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/216/).

Comment: Whether or not a view model pattern is used doesn't seem relevant. The root issue is that an object declared as an `@StateObject` wrapped property will not `deinit`.

Comment: When it’s used correctly it is deinit fine

Comment: What makes this use of `@StateObject` incorrect?